# gpio-key not in sys/kernel/debug/gpio

Tags: embedded, gpio, device-tree, nvidia-jetson

I asked a similar question here: [Embedded - GPIO Key does not register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53014660/embedded-gpio-key-does-not-register) but I am tying to take a step back and focus on just one part of that question.

My board has 3 gpio-keys already built in: power, volume up, and volume down. When calling cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio they show up under GPIOs 256-319, platform/c2f0000.gpio, tegra-gpio-aon: as expected. When in my dts file I create a new gpio-key node, no matter what is in the node, the buttons no longer show up in /sys/kernel/degub/gpio but are lsited in /proc/device-tree/gpio-keys.

If I call my node something different the buttons do not disappear, even if the new node is gpio-key compatible. I should be able to add properties to a node by inheriting from a base dtsi. Why does my additions to the gpio-key seem to disable the other keys?